# Viewing Query Execution/ Estimated Run Time in Teradata

Tags: teradata, execution

I've seen people pull up a tab that shows the order in which the different parts of the query will run, as well as a runtime estimation for each. I believe I found where that capability is referenced in the Teradata documentation:

[image]

However, it seems as if there is a typo in the documentation, as it doesn't tell you what to click in step #1.

Does anyone know how to open the query execution window?

Comment: That sounds like "Visual Explain" which I believe is part of Teradata SQL Assistant, which may only be available with older TTU installs. That being said, you can just add `EXPLAIN` in front of your SELECT statement and Teradata will spit back a full explain plan with details on each step including cost.

Comment: That returns exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Hopefully someone knows the shortcut to getting that view (rather than typing explain into each query) and then I'll be 100% taken care of :)

Comment: If you're using sql assistant or Teradata Studio,  F6 will run the explain.

Comment: Your excerpt from the documention talks about monitoring a query while it's running, which can be done in Viewpoint. If you don't have access to the Query Monitor or My Queries portlet ask your DBA.